# Nodegit How can I get new branch list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, nodegit

```
open(o.localPath).then(function (repo) {
        repository = repo;
        return repo.fetchAll(credentials);
    }).then(function () {
        return repository.getReferenceNames(Git.Reference.TYPE.LISTALL);
    }).then(function (arrayString) {
        console.log(arrayString);   
    }).catch(err => {
        reject(err);
    })
```

I fetched all branches once (5 branches total), and I deleted one branch, local and remote, this still return 5 branches, but it should return 4 branches, how can I get new list of the branch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repository.getReferenceNames(Git.Reference.TYPE.LISTALL);` can be synonymous with

`git show-ref` command.

This is using the references in `.git/refs` folder.

You want to run a `git fetch --all --prune` upon deleting the branch to remove remote tracking references that are removed in the remote.

Depending on your version of nodegit (for [[v0.5.0]](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/v0.5.0/lib/repository.js#L665) and up)

```
//...
const fetchOptions = { callbacks: credentials, pruneAfter: true }
return repo.fetchAll(fetchOptions)
//...
```

For older versions ([v0.4.1](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/v0.4.1/lib/repository.js#L633) - [v0.3.0](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/v0.3.0/lib/repository.js#L633))

```
//...
return repo.fetchAll(remoteCallbacks, true)
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using v0.27.0 and the following works for me:

```
repo.fetchAll({
  callbacks: {
    credentials(url, username) {
      return ...
    }
  },
  prune: Git.Fetch.PRUNE.GIT_FETCH_PRUNE
})
```